# RoR select_tag selected value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'am using `select_tag` and I want to pass selected value in href `:onchange`

I couldnt fetch the selected value

Please guide me how to fetch the selected value and pass in href

I'am using following code

```
<%= select_tag "name", 
   options_for_select(@user.names.map {|c| [c.firstname,c.id]}),
   :onchange =>"document.location.href='/names/value'" %>
```

In the code in `href='/names/**value**` at the place of **value** I have to pass **selected value**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question but you can try this:

```
<%= select_tag "name", options_for_select(@user.names.map {|c| [c.firstname,c.id]}),:onchange =>"document.location.href='/names/'+this.value" %>
```

Thereby, the selected value is used during the onchange event.

Comment: +this.value is printing as it is in the path, getting no value

Comment: Can you give us the html printed ?

Comment: html page is too big...

iam using this select_tag inside form_tag,

and :onchange inside select_tag, it should take me to form with different value

for example if page path is http://localhost:3000/names/1

onclick of selected item with value 2, it should take me to page

http://localhost:3000/names/2

Comment: I just want to see the html for the select_tag ;) with options

Comment: <select id="name" name="name" onchange="document.location.href='/names/+this.value/males/edit">
<option value="1">Ashok</option>
<option value="2">bala</option>
</select>

Comment: i even tried putting value inside {} like #{+this.value}, and no answer

Comment: Hmmm, ok, do this in your :onchange => "document.location.href='/names/'+this.value+'/males/edit'"

And try to change value in your page.

Onchange is javascript option, so it's normal 'this.value' is printed.

Comment: it is still printing '+this.value+' as it is

Comment: In your html, it's normal because is a javascript option.
When you tried to change your value in your select, are you redirect to another page ?

Comment: yes, just the value will be changing, any way its different page

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= select_tag "name", 
   options_for_select(@user.names.map {|c| [c.firstname,c.id]}),
   :onchange => "document.location.href=/names/ + $(this).value" %>
```

Comment: no  + $(this).value  is printing as it is, please tell me if any other way to do this

Comment: But did you try using the select to see what happens? I've tried here and it worked, and it's also printing `+ $(this).value`. Try using the select...

Comment: i used like this


<%= select :name, @user.names.map {|c| [c.firstname,c.id]},
   {:onchange => "document.location.href=/names/ + $(this).value"} %>

but i dont get onchange event

Answer (score 0):

I think the suggested methods j and kiva would not work because the javascript components are rendered (written to the static html file) at the initial stage, rails is server side, and what is suggested in their posts is more client side.

I achieved it like this ->

add a onchange => myJavaScriptFunction()

and then code the url change in the javascript function()
using pure javascript, no rails involvement.

here's my snippet -

```
<%= select_tag :clientid, options_for_select(@options),
      :include_blank => false,
      :onchange => "myfunction(this)"
                %>

  function myfunction(combo_box)
  {
    //var combo1 = document.getElementById('clientid');

    var value1 = combo_box.options[combo_box.selectedIndex].text;
    var value2 = combo_box.selectedIndex;

    document.getElementById('session_dump').innerHTML='<hr>'+value2 + '::::=> ' + value1+'<hr>';

  }
```

Hope its useful...